# Bessere Bezeichnung für "Hautfarbe" bei Stiften

Tags: political-correctness

Viele Sets von Buntstiften oder Filzstiften für Kinder enthalten eine Farbe, die der Hautfarbe hellhäutiger Menschen nachempfunden ist. Es handelt sich um eine Art rötliches Beige. Im Gegensatz zu allen anderen Farben, die je nach Motiv vielfältig eingesetzt werden können, wird diese Farbe meiner Erfahrung nach fast ausschließlich zum Malen von Gesichtern und Körpern verwendet. Die mir bekannte übliche Bezeichnung ist "Hautfarbe" bzw. "hautfarben".

[image: Bild eines "hautfarbenen" Buntstifts]

Diese Namensgebung ist offensichtlich nur aus der Sicht hellhäutiger Menschen korrekt. Die Verwendung dieses Namens impliziert, dass es eine einzige normale Hautfarbe gibt, und dass Menschen mit anderer Hautfarbe von dieser Norm abweichen.

Aus diesem Grund würde ich meinen Kindern gerne eine andere Bezeichnung für diese Farbe nahelegen. Leider fällt mir kein Name ein, der zugleich treffend und prägnant ist:

- Es handelt sich weder um rosa noch um beige.
- "Rosabeige" oder "rötlichbeige" klingt für mich umständlich.

Hat jemand einen Rat, wie man diese Farbe sinnvoll nennen kann?

Comment: Das ist nichtmal aus meiner hellhäutigen Sicht korrekt. Fand das schon als Piepel aus diverden Gründen eher fragwürdigwürdig. Da es sich hier nicht um eine Primärfarbe im klassischen Sinne handelt, gibt es keine eindeutige Antwort. Das ist je nach Hersteller wohl ca. Pastelrosa oder Pastelbeige, liegt zwischen Lachs und Pfirsichpopo

Comment: Diese Farbe nennt sich auch **Lachsfarben**. Im Englischen ["Salmon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmon_(color)), gibt es sogar in Computersyntax als definierte Farbe. Aber vermutlich schon aus Tierrechtsgründen nicht die beste Wahl, denn die Farbe leitet sich her aus dem Fleisch des toten Lachses, nicht der silbrigen Erscheinungsform des lebendig fröhlich Schwimmenden. (Nebenbei, auch die kaukasische Hautfarbe kann als Lachsfarben bezeichnet werden, "Weiß" -- und "Schwarz" oder "Gelb" -- haben hier ebenfalls ein historisches Bias-Problem.) Vielleicht dann einfach: **Hellrosa**.

Comment: Ich empfehle, die Kinder mal unter Rotlicht oder Blaulicht malen zu lassen. Dann merken sie, dass diese Farben gar nicht so exakt definierbar sind wie es scheint.

Comment: Gräser gibt es auch in hunderten Sorten und je nach Boden, Jahreszeit, Zeitpunkt des letzten Regenfalls ist Grasgrün auch recht vage bestimmt. Des weiteren ist wohl zu bezweifeln, dass die Stifthersteller alle den gleichen Farbton in ihr Sortiment aufnehmen. [Faber Castell](https://www.faber-castell.de/produkte/ColourGripChildrenoftheworldBuntstiftdreikant103/201746) bietet einen Malkasten mit 6 extra Hauttönen an, die alle unter Hautton firmieren und von Marzipan (kannst Du als einen Vorschlag betrachten) bis schwarz reichen. Ein anderer Vorschlag wäre ein Name des Musters "Schmincke 226".

Comment: Ich kenne keinen Namen, aber einen praktischen Ansatz. Erkläre deinen Kindern dass Menschen sehr unterschiedliche Hautfarben haben, lasse sie die Farbe mit der eigenen Haut vergleichen. Dann können sie beim Lehrer nachfragen wie man diese und viele andere Farbtöne sinnvoll nennen könnte. Bedenke aber bitte auch dass eine zu intensive Durchsetzung von political correctness bei Mitschüler, anderen Eltern und Lehrern möglicherweise nicht so ankommt wie gewünscht und deine Kinder dies dann ausbaden müssen.

Comment: Idee: Wie heißen denn die Farben bei Make-up? Kann man sich vielleicht daran orientieren?

Comment: Mir gefiele die Frage besser, wenn sie ein neutrales Tag wie [tag:word-choice] hätte. political-correctness kommt mir schon nach einem etwas bemühten Zusammenhang vor, der dem Erläuterungstext des Tags nicht wirklich entspricht.

Comment: "...impliziert, dass es eine einzige normale Hautfarbe gibt, und dass Menschen mit anderer Hautfarbe von dieser Norm abweichen."
Dem würde ich widersprechen. Es impliziert eine historische Vergangenheit, die aufzeigt, dass der Name dieses Farbtons aus einer Sprache stammt, deren Urvolk nunmal eine solche Hautfarbe hatte. Es spricht nichts dagegen, dass jemand mit dunkelerer haut einen braunton als "Hautfarbe" bezeichnet. Weder in der deutschen, noch in irgendeiner anderen Sprache.
Genauso wie Grassgrün, Kaffeebraun, Blutrot oder jeder andere Begriff der sich von einem Objekt/Subjekt ableitet

Comment: @Iris würde denken da wird das gesamte spektrum zwischen super heller "weißer" haut und super dunkeler "schwarzer" haut als "Hautfarbe" bezeichnet, oder? Ich meine, es muss im wahrsten Sinne des Wortes ja die "Hautfarbe"  des anwenders sein. Ich glaube da wird das nach einem Zahlen-Buchstaben-Schema klassifiziert, bei dem hautton und helligkeit entsprechend abgebildet sind. Man kann sich ja nicht x Namen ausdenken, weil x nunmal gigantisch groß ist.

Comment: @Benjamin Basmaci, ich habe inzwischen zuhause nachgeschaut: Ich mische light beige and rose um meinen Hautton zu treffen. Aber ja, die Make-up Farben haben unterschiedliche Namen, wobei es auch da Probleme gibt wie, dass "nude" oder "naturell" weiße Haut bezeichnen.

Comment: "Leuchtendes Gelbliches Pink" (HTML RGB #E4A792)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kunsthistorisch gesehen wäre ein möglicher Begriff [Inkarnat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkarnat)

> Inkarnat ist ein Begriff aus der Kunst, genauer aus der Malerei und der Fassmalerei (Bemalung von Skulpturen u. a.). Er bezeichnet die vom Künstler gewählten Farbtöne, die für die Darstellung nackter menschlicher Körperpartien, also der Haut, verwendet werden.

Da dies aber halt nicht nur eine Farbe ist, sondern diese inklusive aller Farbtöne bezeichnet wenden wir uns mal an die Hersteller.

Faber Castell hat eine [Liste der angebotenen Farben](https://www.faber-castell.de/-/media/Faber-Castell-new/PDF/de/Farbtabelle-A-G.ashx) online. In dieser steht

> 114 hautfarbe hell / **blassrosa**
>
> 116 hautfarbe medium / **apricot**

Online bezeichnet [dieser Thread](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/wie-nennen-dunkelhaeutige-die-farbe-hautfarbe) den Farbton als [RAL 3012](https://www.ralcolorchart.com/ral-classic/ral-3012-beige-red). Dieser wäre:

> RAL 3012 - **Beigerot**

Der im Bild gezeigte Stift wäre, wenn man sich die Farben hinter den Namen anschaut, am ehesten **blassrosa**.

Comment: *Inkarnat* funktioniert, bis das Kind Latein lernt.

Comment: Von Inkarnat bin ich nicht überzeugt; "Hautfarbe" auf Latein bleibt Hautfarbe. ;-)
Aber blassrosa gefällt mir. Auf die Idee, nach den offiziellen Bezeichnungen der Hersteller zu sehen, bin ich nicht gekommen.

Answer (score 4):

In meiner Welt heißt das seit jeher nicht *hautfarben* sondern

> schweinchenfarben

Also: *Gib mir mal den schweinchenfarbenen Stift!*, oder: *Und die Gesichter malen wir schweinchenfarben aus.*

Selbstverständlich ist mir klar, dass Schweine verschiedene Hautfarben haben können und dass es auch gescheckte Schweine gibt. Insofern ist *schweinchenfarben* natürlich genauso problematisch wie *hautfarben*, es sei denn, man nimmt die bei der modernen Massentierhaltung heute überwiegenden hellrosabeigen Schweinerassen als standardgefärbt und somit namengebend an.

Kurios finde ich, dass man schweinchenfarbene Menschen oft als "weiß" bezeichnet.

Comment: Vielen Dank, Christian! Ich musste einmal kurz herzhaft lachen. Hellrosabeigerote Hautfarbe heißt bei mir ab sofort *schweinchenfarben*. Das halte ich für die bisher  beste hier genannte Bezeichnung.

Comment: @Olafant  Wie gesagt, ich habe mir das nicht ausgedacht. In meinem sozialen Umfeld seit Kindheit kennt man diese Farbe (oder Farbgruppe) ausschließlich unter diesem Namen. - Ich darf vielleicht hinzufügen, dass es sich um eine ländlich geprägte Umwelt handelt(e), wo der Kontakt mit frischgeborenen Ferkeln für viele Leute eine Alltagsangelegenheit ist.

Comment: ich kenne die Farbe auch als Schweinchenrosa.

Comment: Es gibt aber auch schwarze Schweine also sind wir wieder am Anfang.

Answer (score 2):

> Im Gegensatz zu allen anderen Farben, die je nach Motiv vielfältig eingesetzt werden können, wird diese Farbe meiner Erfahrung nach **fast ausschließlich zum Malen von Gesichtern und Körpern verwendet**.

Dem muss ich widersprechen, es gibt z.B. viele Blumensorten deren Blütenblätter mit dieser Farbe abgebildet werden.

> Hat jemand einen Rat, wie man diese Farbe sinnvoll nennen kann?

Das ist schlicht und einfach **rosa** (evtl. mit diversen Abtönungen).

---

Der Begriff *Hautfarbe* ist freilich missverständlich, da es die verschiedensten Hautfarben (ausser dieser) bei Menschen gibt.

Comment: Den größeren Kästen liegt aber oft extra ein knalliges Rosa bei.

Comment: "hellrosa" erscheint mir da eine sinnvolle Abgrenzung zu "knallrosa" zu sein.

Comment: @infinitezero Es geht ja um die Abgrenzung zu _hautfarben_ oder nicht?

Comment: Mein Kommentar bezog sich auf vectorys Kommentar.

Answer (score 0):

Es ist meiner Einschätzung nach weiterhin vertretbar ihn hautfarben zu nennen. Zumindest wenn jemand gleicher Hautfarbe nach dieser Stiftfarbe fragt, so ist klar, um welche Farbe es sich handelt. Ich denke nicht, dass der Name impliziert, alle Menschen hätten diese Hautfarbe. Dennoch sollte man, gerade im Umgang mit Kindern, darauf aufmerksam machen, dass es verschiedene Hautfarben gibt und dieser Stift eigentlich korrekter die Farbe "helle/weiße Hautfarbe" heißen sollte. Wie eingangs erläutet, kann man auf das näher beschreibende Adjektiv verzichten, wenn es im Kontext klar ist.

Comment: Nachdem sogar eine andere Antwort auf die offizielle Farbbenennung verweist, die "Hautfarbe hell" angibt, bin ich über die Erklärung, warum es sich hier um eine schlechte Antwort handeln soll, gespannt.

Comment: Mit Weiß hat die Hautfarbe allenfalls zu tun, wenn man Holzschnitte anfertigt - m.a.W. erscheint es mir absurd, bei der Benennung der Stiftfarbe super sensibel sein zu wollen, die Hautfarbe dann aber mit der gröbsten Differenzierung zu benennen, die bezüglich Farben bekannt ist.

Comment: Der gängige Terminus für Personen mit Nordeuropäischem Hautton lautet "weiß".

Comment: Ja, der gängige, und der gängige Stiftton lautet "beige" oder "rosa". Weiß ist in der Regel das Papier, dafür braucht es keinen Stift. Meine Haut ist alles andere als Weiß. Meine Hautfarbe ist schwarz, allerdings, wie ich einräumen muss, ein sehr, sehr helles Schwarz.

Comment: Okay, aber was hat das jetzt mit der oben dargelegten Argumentation zu tun?

Comment: Ich finde die Argumentation schlüssig. Daher +1.

Comment: @infinitezero  Ja, es ist gängig, den in Mitteleuropa traditionell vorherrschenden Hautton "weiß" zu nennen. Ich habe allerdings - erstens - den Verdacht, dass diese Unsitte erst aus den USA importiert wurde (das ließe sich ja durch Korpusuntersuchungen ermitteln). Zweitens ist "weiß" eine blöde Wahl. Kein Mensch ist weiß (und es ist auch keiner schwarz). Alle sind in irgend einer Form braun, die einen heller, die anderen dunkler, und jeweils mit einem anderen Ton noch dabei. - Und überdies ist Hautfarbe sowieso vor allem eine Frage der Beleuchtung.

Comment: Ob Dinge jetzt sinnvoll benannt sind oder nicht, ist eine andere Diskussion. Hier geht es um Eindeutigkeit bei der Farbbezeichnung und diese wird aus dem Kontext deutlich. Wenn ich sage, die Tankenstellenräuberin war 180, blond und weiß, dann weiß jeder Bescheid was ich meine. Zur Farbargumentation bzgl des Stiftes siehe meine Antwort, die das erläutert.

Comment: Daniel Wolf fragte nach einer Bezeichnung, die sowohl treffend, als auch prägnant ist. "Hautfarbe weiß" finde ich aus den genannten Gründen weder prägnant, noch treffend.

Comment: Unter der Annahme, dass die Kinder eine Hautfarbe haben, die der des Stiftes entspricht oder nahe kommt, ist Hautfarbe eine treffende und prägnante Beschreibung des Stifts und sogar eine eindeutige. Der Schluss, dass es auch andere Hautfarben gibt und nur weil der Stift als hautfarben bezeichnet wird nicht bedeutet, dass das die normale Hautfarbe wäre, ist wie erwähnt Aufklärungsarbeit der Eltern.

Comment: "Unter der Annahme, dass die Kinder eine Hautfarbe haben, die der des Stiftes entspricht oder nahe kommt, ist Hautfarbe eine treffende und prägnante Beschreibung des Stifts" Ich denke eben das ist ein Problem mit der Bezeichnung. Was ist mit einer Familie bei der das nicht zutrifft? Hautfarbe hell / mittel / dunkel wie Faber sie alternativ nennt ist eine Möglichkeit. Aber das ist nicht idiomatisch. Besser sind dann aber eindeutige Farbbezeichnungen (blassrosa, apricot), dann wissen alle wovon man spricht. Außer den meisten Männern ^^.

Comment: Ich sehe den Punkt, dass eine andere Farbbezeichnung besser ist, denke jedoch nicht, dass es notwendig ist, den "hautfarbenen Stift" in die politisch unkorrekte Schublade zu legen. Ich persönlich finde deine ( @mtwde ) Antwort auch am besten.

Comment: Die Verallgemeinerung von blassrosa zu "Hautfarbenen Stift" ist Rassismus und nichts anderes.

Comment: Es wird ja auch nicht von blassrosa zu Hautfarbenem Stift verallgemeinert. Der Kontext ist wichtig. In Subsahara-Afrika wird dem hautfarbenem Stift sicher eine andere Farbe als blassrosa zugewiesen werden. Daher, wie so oft, context matters.

Comment: @Iris inwiefern ist das bitte Rassismus? Laut duden ist Rassismus "Lehre, Theorie, nach der Menschen bzw. Bevölkerungsgruppen mit bestimmten biologischen Merkmalen hinsichtlich ihrer kulturellen Leistungsfähigkeit anderen von Natur aus **über- bzw. unterlegen** sein sollen"
Das trifft bei der Diskussion auf dieser gesamten Seite bisher nicht zu.

Comment: Es gibt deutlich mehr und ausführlichere Definitionen von Rassismus https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rassismus#Begriffliche_Differenzierung. In Deutschland zu sagen Hautfarben = weiße Haut schließt viele Menschen aus. Der Kontext von dem @infinitezero schreibt ist aber nunmal, dass wir in Deutschland über weiße Haut = Hautfarben diskutieren und nicht Menschen in der Subsahara-Afrika über ihre Hautfarbe.

Comment: Mein Post ist bis auf den Bezug zu diesem speziellen Stift in der Frage übrigens komplett neutral und lässt sich problemlos auf alle anderen hautfarbenen Stifte anwenden. Mir jetzt Rassismus nahelegen zu wollen weise ich entschieden zurück.

Answer (score 0):

> Diese Namensgebung ist offensichtlich nur aus der Sicht hellhäutiger Menschen korrekt.

Dieser Name unterliegt aber auch keinerlei Marken- bzw. Gebrauchsmusterschutz d.h. dass es jedem Produzenten frei steht, andere Farbvarianten unter demselben Namen anzubieten. Es liegt am Konsumenten, diese von den Produzenten einzufordern. Dann würde sich sicherlich eine Differenzierung herausbilden (z.B. hautfarben Europa*, hautfarben Lateinamerika*, hautfarben Zentralafrika*, hautfarben Ostasien*; * inkl. Personen mit europäischem/lateinamerikanischem/zentralafrikanischem/ostasiatischem Migrationshintergrund). Denn bei einem hast du natürlich recht: Diese Farbe wird vornehmlich für Hautpartien verwendet, auch wenn sie sich ebenfalls für Blüten eignet. Nur bin ich mir recht sicher, dass Konsumenten, die einen Satz Buntstifte kaufen, darin die von ihnen benötigten Farben haben wollen. Und am besten nur diese, weil man sonst für etwas bezahlt, was man weniger/nicht braucht. Man will also die gebräuchlichsten Farben haben.

> Die Verwendung dieses Namens impliziert, dass es eine einzige normale Hautfarbe gibt, und dass Menschen mit anderer Hautfarbe von dieser Norm abweichen.

Die Verwendung dieses Namens impliziert lediglich, dass "hautfarben (Europa)" die gebräuchlichste (Zeichen-)Hautfarbe in Zentraleuropa ist. Eine Implikation, wie du sie beschreibst, fällt sofort in sich zusammen, sobald du deine Kinder nach draußen (vor allem in Städten) mitnimmst. Aber auch Yakari und Dora mit Freunden helfen da kräftig mit.

Übrigens habe ich als weißhäuiger Mensch nichts dagegen, dass man unter einem Bild, das einen schwarzhäutigen Menschen abbildet, schlicht "Mensch" schreibt. Damit ist nicht gesagt, dass es nur solche Menschen gibt. Warum sollte also der Name "hautfarben" bei einem rosa-ähnlichen Stift für Unbehagen sorgen? Ich meine hier bei uns. Wenn man tatsächlich "hautfarben Europa" den Leuten in Zentralafrika andrehen wollte, sähe die Sache natürlich ganz anders aus.

Falls es nicht deutlich geworden ist, brauchen wir meines Erachtens keinen neuen Namen, sondern gegebenfalls eine Differenzierung des Namens 'hautfarben'. Es versteht sich dann wohl von selbst, dass ich keinen Vorschlag in Richtung "rosairgendwas" bzw. "irgendwasrosa" abgebe.

Comment: -1, da der Vorschlag rosa Farbe = *hautfarben (Europa)* rassistisch. Europa ist ja eben nicht schweinchenrosa Farben!

Comment: @Iris Erstens ist Europa bunt durch Migration. Ich bin auch auf den jeweiligen Migrationshintergrund eingegangen. Zweitens hat Rassismus etwas mit (negativer) Wertung zu tun. Hier handelt es sich um eine wertfreie Zuordnung von (historisch gesehen) prädominanter Hautpigmentierung in bestimmten Weltregionen zu Buntstiftfarben. Erst wenn man "hautfarbe - XYZ" als minderwertig ansieht, ist es Rassismus. Es ist nicht alles Gold, was glänzt. Es ist nicht alles Rassismus, was von Hautpigmentierung handelt. "blauäugig" ist auch nicht rassistisch, obwohl viele Menschen es nie richtig sein können.

Comment: Ich bin von deiner Argumentation nicht überzeugt. Für mich ist das ein Fall von "das ist nicht rassistisch, aber"

Comment: Somit scheinst du eine andere Argumentation überzeugender zu finden. Wie lautet sie? Ich vermute, dass darin eine kategorische Nichtbeschäftigung mit der Hautpigmentierung/Hautfarbe vorkommt. Mit dem "aber" kann ich nicht viel anfangen, weil ich nicht weiß, wer das ganze Zitat ausgesprochen haben könnte.

Comment: Ich habe übrigens inzwischen eine Vision, den Buntstiftkauf betreffend, entwickelt. Man nimmt einen Buntstiftkasten aus dem Regal. Dieser enthält einen leeren Platz für die meistbenutzte Sonderfarbe. Anschließend greift man in einen Behälter mit losen Buntstiften, die u.a. unterschiedliche Hautpigmentierungen nachahmen. Man vergleicht diese mit einer Vorlage z.B. Haut, Foto o.ä., ärgert sich, dass keiner so richtig passt, und geht mit einem oder mehreren zur Kasse. Es steht einem frei, alle erworbenen Buntstifte gleichberechtigt in ein Glas zu stellen.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt Farben wie 'Sand' oder 'Schlamm' (entspricht mehr oder weniger 'taupe' = 'maulwurffarben'), die farblich nicht so genau festgelegt sind, warum dann den Stift nicht einfach 'Haut' nennen. Ich stell mir das auch rein praktisch vor: *Welchen Stift soll ich für das Gesicht nehmen?* - *Nimm doch einfach den apricotfarbenen* hört sich etwas komplizierter an als *Nimm einfach den Hautstift*, und wenn mehrere da sind *den hellen / mittleren / dunkleren Hautstift.* Noch besser für Kinder wäre allerdings *Marzipanschweinchenstift* - der Vorschlag fiel bereits. Zwar auch ein Bandwurmwort, aber damit kann man herrlichen Blödsinn machen.